# Fastapi and Pydantic: How to nest objects?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Let's say I have an object "user" and an object "article".
It is defined (in a simplified version here) in Pydantic as:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config: 
        orm_mode = True
```

and

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: text
    author_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Now, I want the following to fall out of fastAPI:

```
{article: {"id": 1, ""text":"article text", "authorId": 1}, author: {"id":1, "name": "Bob"}}
```

How do I do this with pydantic? Do I create an extra class with nested dicts? Is there another way? What is the elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Create a schema that describes the response you want:

```
class ArticleResponse(BaseModel):
    article: Article
    author: User
```

You then configure this as the response model for your view with `response_class=ArticleResponse` in your view decorator:

```
@router.get("/{article_id}", response_class=ArticleResponse)
def ..:
    return ArticleResponse(article=article, author=article.author)
```